# Bootstrap Column grid, min-height

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, col

I have a jsfiddel here - http://jsfiddle.net/ryz4wugo

I'm using bootstrap It's four columns with varying amounts of text.

When the window is resized and the layout moves to two columns, block three is pushed to the right and block four pushed down.

Bootstrap uses floats to position the columns and because the blocks are different heights the grid is pushed out of space.

I don't want to override bootstraps floats because that will cause other problems.

Is the best way to fix this with min-height, are there any problems with min-height in ie.

```
        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">


                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 block">
                    <p>
                        <span>ONE</span>   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, Ut enim ad minim veniam, Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    </p>    
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 block">
                     <p>
                        <span>TWO</span>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    </p>   
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 block">
                     <p>
                        <span>THREE</span>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, 
                    </p>   
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 block">
                     <p>
                        <span>FOUR</span>  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    </p>   
                </div>

            </div>    

        </div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap has addressed this in their docs: Since it's supposed to add to 12, you add a clearfix visible only on that breakpoint:         <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div> after the 12 at that breakpoint: http://jsfiddle.net/ryz4wugo/10/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this by using `clear: left;` to 3rd column.

### JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ryz4wugo/4/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 block">
        ......
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 block">
        ......
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 block" style="clear: left;">
        ......
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 block">
        ......
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**OR:** Just add this line in your stylesheet.css

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ryz4wugo/5/)**

**CSS:**

```
.row div:nth-child(3) {
    clear: left;
}
```

---

As per `Bootstrap` CSS `@media` queries:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f6hMD/32/) or [Full Screen View](http://jsfiddle.net/f6hMD/32/show/)**

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .row .col-sm-6:nth-child(3) {
        clear: left !important;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .row .col-md-3:nth-child(3) {
        clear: none !important;
    }
}
```

---

### [EDITED]    -    [Thanks to [@Christina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004312/christina)!]

Bootstrap has a way of addressing this. Since it's supposed to add to 12, you add a clearfix visible only on that breakpoint: `<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>` after the 12 at that breakpoint:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ryz4wugo/10/)**

Clearfix visible with jQuery fallback for the equal heights responsive script.

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ryz4wugo/12/)**

---

Comment: But I still won't know which column to clear as I don;t know the exact content.

Comment: @ttmt I think there is some problem saving the demo - try to add this line in your stylesheet then let me know if it doesn't work for you... = `@media (min-width: 768px){.row div:nth-child(3) {clear: left !improtant;}}`

Comment: Hi Mary, this just shows 2 columns, if you expand the page it dosen't go to 4 cols.

Comment: @ttmt Yeah! almost done - I'm trying to use a css selector for third column, Please wait... - http://jsfiddle.net/f6hMD/29/

Comment: @ttmt now it's done check it out - http://jsfiddle.net/f6hMD/32/show/ or http://jsfiddle.net/f6hMD/32/

Comment: @ttmt You could also use a custom css class for the 3rd column inside the `@media` queries. I've updated my answer as well with this - http://jsfiddle.net/f6hMD/32/show/ or http://jsfiddle.net/f6hMD/32/

Comment: @MaryMelody -- bootstrap has a way of addressing this. Since it's supposed to add to 12, you add a clearfix visible only on that breakpoint:         <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div> after the 12 at that breakpoint: http://jsfiddle.net/ryz4wugo/10/

Comment: Since this is a bootstrap question, it would be more beneficial to add the way bootstrap recommends so you don't have any css to add to your site. http://jsfiddle.net/ryz4wugo/10/

Comment: @Christina Thanks and it could be an answer instead of suggesting me, its the perfect solution. :)

Comment: Just add to yours, I already upvoted yours until I remembered reading it in their docs.

Comment: Here's another way, with the fallback, http://jsfiddle.net/ryz4wugo/12/ -- jQuery (which is required in Bootsrap) and the equal heights responsive script.

Comment: For more information see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets and http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes